# How graduate the correct belt tension

Tags: belt, corexy, belt-printer

I moved a little the belt tension, and now the last layer is awful and weird. How I will know the correct tension? My printer is a custom BLV 220 x 220 x 280.

I think and I am almost sure, that this happened because the filament got a little tangled in the profile where I put the spool of it while printing, but, last week this happened, and since that moment, it has been having problems, which I am going to show and explain.

The top-left corner, after I started to change the tension belt, was worst, because the corner was more pronounced, pulling as elongated, in the image you can see a little, but it was worse the last few days.

And now, the rectangle orange, is new, because yesterday I changed the tension belt, and the last layer is like I show in the image.

[image: one]

At this moment, I am testing different tension, but the result is worse.

[image: double]

Comment: What do you mean by "graduate", I don't understand the context, but I'm not native English speaking. Know that belt tension is not very critical unless it is a CoreXY. Looking at the images you seem to have a problem with layer shifting. It could be beneficial to add photos of you setup and a view of the belt and how it is connected to the hotend carriage.

Comment: @0scarHi, I am from Colombia, I talked to the person who assemble the machine, so I follow his instructions, like check the belt tension, and can solve at the moment, is not the best result, but having a scale from 1 to 10, now is 9

Comment: Belt tension is usually not a big issue, unless it is too loose (positioning or backlash issues) or too tight (hardware issues, high resistance). Judging your images, you are probably having other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced users of the printers just know it by feel, but for newbies there are apps for Android, like:

[Belt tension meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.gr.java_conf.kotokotobokan.onpa3&hl=en_US) (Newtons)

[Easy Tension](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.hutchinsontransmission.tensiometre&hl=en&gl=US) (lbf)

There are probably iPhone apps like that, I don't know them personally.

You measure and enter dimensions of your belt mechanism (as instructed by the app), then "strum" the belt (like a guitar string) within reach of your phone's microphone, and the app converts the frequency to force in Newtons or Pounds Force.

The "best" tension varies from printer to printer, but generally falls between 15N and 25N (~3.5 - 6 lbf); if you don't know what is *best* on your printer, going with 20N/4.5lbf is a safe bet that will produce *reasonable* results.

Comment: Wow, interesting explanation and the apps I didn't know about that. At the moment I solved the problem, the result is not the better, but at least work close to the normal print result.